# how to solve missing hibernate-support library in copied netbeans project

Tags: java, hibernate, ubuntu, netbeans-7

I am working on this Java code given using NetBeans. I copy code and trying to run and getting following error:

> Warning: Could not find file
> /home/blackbird/NetBeansProjects/XCRIBuilder/${libs.hibernate-support.classpath}
> to copy**

In `NetBeans --> project properties` it says missing `hibernate-support` library, but I can see there are multiple hibernate related jar files already added to library.

Is there any classPath need to set-up for hibernate? If I create new java web-application project in NetBeans then it doesn't give me this error.

I am running NetBeans on Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

In `Project properties->Libraries` I removed the `hibernate-support` reference and then added hibernate directly from Netbeans, i.e. `Add Library -> Global Libraries -> Hibernate 4.3.x`

**Clean and build** and everything should be fine.