# ${libs.hibernate-support.classpath} to copy

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans - Java, I been given project which was initially missing some libraries and it seems fine however I am getting warning

```
C:\Users\zahikhu\Desktop\My Work\My Project\University Main WebSite\XCRI implementation\XCRI\Workspace\XCRIBuilder\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1024: Warning: Could not find file C:\Users\zahikhu\Desktop\My Work\My Project\University Main WebSite\XCRI implementation\XCRI\Workspace\XCRIBuilder\${libs.hibernate-support.classpath} to copy.
```

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

how I solve hibernate issue

```
${libs.hibernate-support.classpath}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to solve missing hibernate-support library in copied netbeans project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912930/how-to-solve-missing-hibernate-support-library-in-copied-netbeans-project)